# LinkedIn SDK Logout Error: 'no XD object is available from this page'

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm currently using the LinkedIn JS SDK as documented [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk) for my AngularJS application. I'm inserting the following script into the head block of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
   api_key: [apiKey]
   authorize: false
</script>
```

Then I initiate authorization with an onclick function on a button like so

```
IN.User.authorize(function(){
   callback();
});
```

At this point the user is authenticated with LinkedIn and I can use LinkedIn's APIs.

When the user decides to log out, I use the call `IN.User.logout()` to end the user's session. However, the call causes this error ['Uncaught Error: no XD object is available from this page'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuci4.png) to appear in the JavaScript console.

This only happen sometimes, and I'm unsure of why this exact issue occurs. Most of the time, the SDK will logout the session normally. I make sure that the LinkedIn framework is loaded before calling any functions and I call `IN.User.isAuthorized()` before making a call to logout. Does anyone have an idea of what I may be doing wrong?

```
if (IN.User.isAuthorized()) {  // Returns true
    IN.User.logout();  // Prints `'Uncaught Error: no XD object is available from this page' error
}
```

EDIT:

I'm looking more into the source code and it shows this function being called:

```
Sslac.Function("IN.Support.getXD", function() {
    function a() {
        throw Error("no XD object is available from this page");
    }
    try {
        return IN.Support.isSingleJS() && IN.Support.isPopup() ? IN.Support.generateXDProxy() : IN.Support.isPopup() ? window.opener.getXD || a : IN.Support.isIframe() ? window.parent.getXD || a : a
    } catch (b) {
        return a
    }
}());
```

But the `IN.Support` object is null which is why this error is being thrown. Could anyone from LinkedIn help with this? It looks like there's some kind of race condition.

Answer (score 0):

I could not fix the `'no XD object is available from this page'` error. As a workaround, I called the logout URL itself to end the user session. This still causes the error to appear in the console but the logout function fully completes this way.